# extract the first result of each string, return two records of each string

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT DISTINCT rat.RESPUESTA_TPX 
FROM ROBOT_ALTA_TARIFA rat 
WHERE rat.RESPUESTA_TPX LIKE 'Error en inicio de sesion TPX. Existe%' 
  AND rat.RESPUESTA_TPX LIKE 'Error #5027: GXGeneralException: Requested sequence&'
ORDER BY rat.RESPUESTA_TPX 
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

I am trying to extract the first result of each string, that is, this query would have to return two records with the two strings that are in the logical AND operator but it is returning it to me as empty.

But if I try for example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT rat.RESPUESTA_TPX 
FROM ROBOT_ALTA_TARIFA rat 
WHERE rat.RESPUESTA_TPX LIKE 'Error en inicio de sesion TPX. Existe%'
ORDER BY rat.RESPUESTA_TPX 
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

That returns results but I want two registers at the same time.

How can I do?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: DO you maybe just need an `OR` (instead of `AND`) in your `WHERE` clause? After all - the `RESPUESTA_TPX` column cannot **possibly be** these two values at the same time ....

Comment: with OR only return one record.. @marc_s

Comment: Well - errrh.... - yes, **OF COURSE** you only get one row - **YOU'RE ASKING FOR THAT!!** `FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY`. ....

Comment: @marc_s thats why im asking, i don tknow how can obtain the two values haha

Comment: Well - just **don't use** that `FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY` ...... seem quite obvious...

Comment: It would be interesting to see how the same value can match to two different prefix values as specified in `AND`. Or what is the meaning of "two strings that are in the logical AND operator"?

Answer (score 1):

As [@marc_s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13302/marc-s) tells you :

```
SELECT DISTINCT rat.RESPUESTA_TPX
  FROM ROBOT_ALTA_TARIFA rat 
 WHERE rat.RESPUESTA_TPX LIKE 'Error en inicio de sesion TPX. Existe%' 
    OR rat.RESPUESTA_TPX LIKE 'Error #5027: GXGeneralException: Requested sequence&'
ORDER BY rat.RESPUESTA_TPX;
```